# Is it ok to keep on updating Date Time using Javascript's setInterval method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies, setinterval

I am using Javascript's setInterval method to keep on updating the time of the Client computer. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() { setCookieForDate(); }, 500);
});

function setCookieForDate() {
    var cookie_date = new Date();
    var serverDateTime = '<%=DateTime.Now%>';
    document.cookie = "LocalDate=" + cookie_date.toLocaleString() + "|" + serverDateTime;
}
```

Problem is that sometimes i still get stale (old) value.
when the value is being retrieved, it retrieves the old value even if when I check the cookie value it shows the UPDATED value.

Can any one suggest me any kind of modification in this code?

Comment: Can you give us a more detail example, what you get, and what do you expect to get on your values because I can not fully understand what is your real problem.

Comment: @Aristos "LocalDate=Friday, September 17, 2010 8:11:53 PM|9/17/2010 8:26:24 AM" this is wat i get.But the problem is that when i check the value it shows me the UPDATED VALUE  and when C# code reads it, it takes the old value. Dont knw what happens it takes some stale value like take an e.g. current time is 8:26:24 AM and it will take time when page was loaded say if it was loaded on 8:20:20 AM. Then my C# code will take the Older value. The reason behind doing this is that i want to send a mail in that i want 2 send the Client's Computer time irrespective of the time zone

Comment: for that i am keeping the track of clients pc time and the server's time and the i am taking difference and adds into the server's time so that i can print me the clients local pc time